# facebook - share dynamic information

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I have several lists dynamically added through PHP on my web page. I would like to be able to share the lists on facebook individually depending on which share button is clicked. How can I do this with the API? Take it easy this is my first venture into facebook integration. Thanks in advance!

Comment: post some of your code that generated the list.

Comment: Pretty sure the "share" button is deprecated in favor of the "like" button.

Comment: Heera the LCD screen on my personal computer went out, so I am in the process of getting that fixed then I will be able to place code up here. As always though, a programming mind never shuts off:) @Michael Pryor that is good to know, but how can I accomplish my task similar to SO shares a question on fb and g+?

Answer (score 0):

I'll edit this answer once you post your code (If I have anything to add ofc), but I'll tell you the steps that I took to integrate the like button with my client's website.

I first went to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and designed the like button to the desired look & feel. From there, I went ahead and added the like button to every product page (It's more of a catalog site). From here, it only works for one product. The next step you should take, would be to change the information dynamically through PHP for each product (the link and pictures, etc). Test and tweak till it works how you desire.

Apparently the share button is now called the send button: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

tldr; I explained my process of integrating a like button into http://ohmybloominthreads.com/ . Then I found the "share" button.

****Note: There is important information in the  tag that you should edit.***

ex. (using Open Graph http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ )

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<title that appears>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="<Type of item>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<Image URL>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<URL to link to>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<Site Name>" />
```

Not sure if you understood any of my gibberish, but I hope it at least points you in the right direction.